# Even distribution of colours

Tags: java

It's a pretty basic question however I can't understand it very well I'm afraid.

What I'm trying to do is spawn squares a certain colour out of 3 colours. each colour has it's own number value `(-1, 0, 1)` what I will then do is add that to a 2D array making a grid of squares.

For blue, it's a 1/4 chance. For red it's a 1/4 chance. For white it's a 1/2 chance.

I understand how to use Java's Random class, however I'm not quite sure how to implement what I'm looking for.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: post some code, and explain exactly what you would like to do?

Answer (score 0):

Create a (1D) array the size of the number of squares, put the proportionate number of each colour into the array, random sort it (Collections.shuffle), and then pop them all off and into your 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone point me in the right direction?

- Create a square 2D array of `int`'s: `int[][] matrix = new int[SIZE][SIZE]`
- Fill it using random numbers from 0 to 3

  CORRESPONDENCES (for example)

  - 0-1 yellow
  - 2 blue
  - 3 red
- Iterate over the 2D array and in each iteration:

  - [draw a rectangle](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/DrawRectangle.htm)
  - increase `y` value (position) in each inner iteration and `x` in outer
  - assign color depending the value of the array.
  - **HOW?** Executing something like this method each iteration

    ```
    //this will draw a square of size 50 at position x,y colored
    public void paint(Graphics g, int color){
      switch (color) {
      case 2:
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        break;
      case 3:
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        break;
      default:
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        break;
      }
      g.drawRect(x,y,50,50);
    }
    ```

That's it, I think you have enough to achieve your goal.

Comment: This part I understand how to do, Its just the chance part i'm having trouble with, so the way i'd like to have it is for each square to have a 1/4 chance to be blue, a 1/4 chance to be red and a 1/2 chance to be white.

Comment: @DanielMunoz the chances are done choosing 4 numbers, 2 (1/2) for yellow, and 1 (1/4) with other colors....

Comment: @DanielMunoz si tienes problemas con el ingles (como yo). Traduzco: las posibilidades se hacen con el `Random` coges 4 numeros, por lo tanto, el 50% de posibilidades son 2 numeros que asignas al amarillo, cada uno de los otros numeros son un 25% de posibilidades, por lo que tienes 1/2 y 1/4 respectivamente

Comment: Yes I understand how that works, but through using random how is it achieved?

Comment: You said in the question *I understand how to use Java's Random class*

Comment: get a new randomizer: `Random generator = new Random();` and get an int between 0 and 3: `int i = generator.nextInt(3);` that's it